# Order of data retrieved from parse

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, nsmutablearray

I am a beginner , i am trying to retrieve user details from `_User` class like this :

```
 var data:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

 func loadData() {

    data.removeAllObjects()

    var userQuery = PFUser.query()
        userQuery?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, erroe) -> Void in

            if let objects = objects {

                for object in objects {

                    if let user = object as? PFUser {

                        if user.objectId != PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId {

                            self.data.addObject(object)



                        }

                        self.tableView.reloadData()


                    }

                }



            }




        })
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadData()

}
```

Here i've a problem that `data` contains all the objects from Parse but the data is being retrieved randomly, i want to give it an order like the latest user will be at the last position , or in last cell in `UITableView` and the 1st user would be in 1st cell.. Thanks for your time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PFQuery has function for Sorting you can sort using `createdAt` or `updatedAt` key in both order:

```
 userQuery.orderByAscending("createdAt")
```

Or:

```
  userQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt")
```

Answer (score 2):

For sortable types like numbers and strings, you can control the order in which results are returned:

// Sorts the results in ascending order by the score field

```
query.orderByAscending("createdAt")
```

// Sorts the results in descending order by the score field

```
query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
```

refer to this Parse.com API doc link

[Parse.com iOS API Doc](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries)